# WM_PRINTCLIENT (and related) documentation confusion-related questions

Tags: winapi, paint, msdn

I'm a bit confused by the MSDN page for `WM_PRINTCLIENT` and related functionality in a few ways:

1. What value should I return from my window procedure? The documentation is missing a "Return value" section entirely. (It is also missing in the Visual Studio 2012 offline documentation disc's version of the page.) [Raymond Chen's original scratch program returns zero](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/07/23/54576.aspx); is this the preferred option?
2. The summary and Remarks section for `WM_PRINTCLIENT` indicates that I should only draw the client area, but the LPARAM lists all the possible `WM_PRINT` flags — so what should I do, ignore it and unconditionally draw just the client area or draw everything requested? (My intention with this question is not to second-guess the documentation; I'm just looking to implement this message correctly.)
3. I want to, as a convenience/kindness, provide the `WM_PAINT` with DC in wParam functionality mentioned in the `WM_PAINT` documentation as an option as well. How should I interpret LPARAM in this case? Or is there a reason I shouldn't provide this alternative route? (Corollary: if LPARAM is to be ignored, should I draw the entire client area unconditionally?)

Thanks.

**Update** Rephrasing the third part:

The documentation for `WM_PAINT` includes the paragraph

> For some common controls, the default WM_PAINT message processing checks the wParam parameter. If wParam is non-NULL, the control assumes that the value is an HDC and paints using that device context.

I would like to provide this behavior in my control in addition to `WM_PRINTCLIENT` for completeness's sake. Is there a reason I should NOT do so? And if doing so wouldn't hurt, how should I interpret the lParam, and should I draw the entire client rect?

Comment: Raymond Chen's [original scratch program](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030723-00/?p=43073) — updated link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What value should I return from my window procedure?

You return 0 to indicate that the message was handled.  Do not call DefWindowProc().

> but the LPARAM lists all the possible WM_PRINT flags

That was a bit sloppy, a copy/paste fumble from the WM_PRINT article.  The only flags you should test are PRF_ERASEBKGND, but only if your draw method requires having the background painted, and PRF_CLIENT, which will always be set in common usage of the message.

> How should I interpret LPARAM in this case?

Hard to decode that question, WM_PAINT doesn't use the lparam argument.  But yes, you want a common function that implements the painting so you can call it both from your WM_PAINT and your WM_PRINTCLIENT message handlers.  Boilerplate code in your window procedure ought to look like:

```
case WM_PAINT: {
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    Draw(hdc);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
}
case WM_PRINTCLIENT: {
    HDC hdc = (HDC)wParam;
    DWORD flags = (DWORD)lParam;
    if (flags & PRF_ERASEBKGND) SendMessage(hWnd, WM_ERASEBKGND, (WPARAM)hdc, NULL);
    if (flags & PRF_CLIENT)     Draw(hdc);
    break;
}
```

Where `void Draw(HDC hdc)` is your common paint function.

Comment: Thanks. That answers the first two questions. I know to do that for part 3; that wasn't what I meant, though. I rephrased that part of the question in the original question.

Comment: No, that's just nonsense.  Use the code I showed you.

Comment: All right, thanks then! (I had that code already anyway, I just wanted to be safe and double-check the things I wasn't sure about with this question.)

Comment: In some cases like handling **LVS_EX_TRANSPARENTBKGND** Listview style, you need to return **TRUE** from **WM_PRINTCLIENT** or your background won't be painted.
see https://sanje2v.wordpress.com/2010/03/23/wm_printclient-may-return-need-to-return-a-value/